# All permutations of n numbers in depth first manner

Tags: algorithm, brute-force

How can I generate all permutations (order matters) with replacements and order matters from a set of `n` numbers, that contain `m` elements in each combination?

I don't want to use more memory, as soon as I generate a combination, I want to use it.

Comment: Is (2,2,1) and (1,2,2) should be both generated? (does order matter)?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that if order matters and replacements are allowed, you basically have `n` options to choose each element (`m` of those) - and the amount of choices you have remains constant.

This means you have `n*n*...*n = n^m` possible combinations.

To generate them, you can use recursion:

Python code: (If you don't know python, just read it as pseudo code, it's pretty clear).

```
def generateAll(numbers, m, currentPermutation=[]):
    if m == 0:
        doSomething(currentPermutation)
        return
    for x in numbers:
        currentPermutation.append(x)
        generateAll(numbers, m-1, currentPermutation)
        currentPermutation.pop()
```

For example, if we define

```
def doSomething(l):
    print str(l)
```

and run

```
generateAll([1,2,3], 4)
```

Output will print all combinations with repalcements, where order matters, of size 4 from [1,2,3]:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 3, 1]
[1, 1, 3, 2]
[1, 1, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 3, 1, 1]
[1, 3, 1, 2]
[1, 3, 1, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 2, 2]
[1, 3, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 3, 3]
[2, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 1, 3]
[2, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 2, 2]
[2, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 3, 1]
[2, 1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 1, 3]
[2, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 3, 1]
[2, 2, 3, 2]
[2, 2, 3, 3]
[2, 3, 1, 1]
[2, 3, 1, 2]
[2, 3, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 2, 2]
[2, 3, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 3, 3]
[3, 1, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2, 2]
[3, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 1, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 3, 2]
[3, 1, 3, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1, 3]
[3, 2, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 2, 2]
[3, 2, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 3, 2]
[3, 2, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 1, 1]
[3, 3, 1, 2]
[3, 3, 1, 3]
[3, 3, 2, 1]
[3, 3, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 3, 1]
[3, 3, 3, 2]
[3, 3, 3, 3]
```